# FLexQueue - Job Id not recognized

Tags: apex-flex-queue

I am following exactly the example of [FlexQueue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_FlexQueue.htm) class, although there is a small syntax problem in the example, with an extra `)`.

The problem I have, is that the jobId returned from `System.EnqueueJob` is not usable in `FlexQueue` methods. In their example, they use `moveBeforeJob`, but I also tried other method like `moveJobToFront`. I get the error:

> Job with id 7076000002UAOmjAAH not found in the queue

If I query this job in developer console, the system finds it well.

Has anybody faced the same problem?

Comment: What kind of job are you enqueuing? `Queueable`?

Comment: yes exactly, a class that implements Queueable.